# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("MyString",typeof(string)) fails. Is this even possible?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm using C# to deserialize some json values to various types.  I don't know what the types are at compile time, those types are determined through reflection at runtime.  For an overly simplistic example, consider the following valid (but dumb) json.

```
{
    "boolean": "true",
    "integer": "42",
    "string": "MyString"
}
```

Each value in the json is actually a string, but some of them can be deserialized into more useful types.  My program reads in the json, determines from external sources what types it expects to actually in those values, and attempts to deserialize them.

This works perfectly for booleans and integers.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("42",typeof(integer))` ends up deserializing the string "42" to an actual integer of 42, exactly as expected.

However, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("MyString",typeof(string))` doesn't work at all.   I get the following exception

`{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 1, position 1."}  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`

Is it just not possible to deserialize a string to a string?  I would expect it to basically do nothing.  Instead, it throws an exception.

Obviously the simple solution is to just do a type check before invoking DeserializeObject, and if the type is string to just not try at all.  That's probably what I'll end up doing, I just would like to understand exactly what's happening and why it is necessary, if possible.

Comment: try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("\"MyString\"",typeof(string))`

Comment: I would say you are going about this wrong somehow, but without seeing the full code it's hard to say. How do you get those values? I assume you are deserializing into `Dictionary<string, string>` and then deserializing again, this is wrong because they have already been deserialized. `"42"` is the JSON representation of the string `42`, you can parse it into an `int` but that is not what the JSON is. Same with `"true"` which is not a JSON boolean, it's just the string `true`. Equally `"MyString"` is JSON representation for `MyString` and you should not be deserializing it again.

Comment: Why your JSON source add Boolean and integer as strings !, in my opinion the source of JSON should add value in correct form instead of try to figure out what is the correct type in deserialization process

Comment: `doesn't work at all.` Because it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: string is string ... why are you trying to convert a string with Json Deserialize to other string?

Comment: Apparently I wasn't clear enough. I'm not actually typing that specific line of code into my program. The actual code is much more complicated and I tried to simplify it down.

The actual code is `var paramValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageParam.Value, methodParameters[i].ParameterType);` where messageParam is a KeyValuePair<string,string> and methodParameters is the ParameterInfo[] on the method we're trying to invoke.  The program checks to see what parameter types the method needs, then tries to convert the string to the right type

Comment: Actually . . . . maybe I should just be casting.  I was using JsonConvert because the messageParam KeyValuePair was created from Json, but once it's in a keyvaluepair it's not actually json at all anymore.  I've already converted it out of json and now I just need to do normal casting

Answer (score 2):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` expects actual JSON in the string. Those quotes just frame the C# string, they're not part of the JSON itself.

`"42"` is actually `42`, which is a valid JSON number. But `"MyString"` is `MyString`, which is not valid JSON and therefore does not parse.

The solution? Add additional (escaped) quotes: `"\"MyString\""`.